# HTTP Request doesn't get to web server

Tags: apache-http-server, webserver

so I got a little VPS with debian on it an apache installed. I can ssh into it. I now expected to be able to do http://ip.to.server to get the basic apache HTML page displayed (the one usually at /var/www/html). [it is enabled] But somehow I never get a response. So I checked the access log which was empty, so apache actually never gets to handle the request.

I'm not a big crack in this but I though, maybe the port is just closed, so I checked port 80 with nmap, getting:

```
PORT   STATE    SERVICE
80/tcp filtered http
```

So it might be, that the system admin just didn't configure it "right".

What can I test on my side (I can just do anything with the server itself but I can't e.g. access the routers config etc.) to make sure it's not a problem on my side?

Comment: Use a program like Fiddler to see if the request is being sent properly. If it's being stopped by your firewall, that's a problem.

Comment: sorry for the late answer - I did a trace route and it seemed to arrive at the server but then somehow doesn't get routed to my web server. I'll look into fiddler too. ty